# Joomla broken links

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, http-status-code-404, broken-links

how does broken link works in Joomla?

For example i have here this link:

http://www.cedera-okna.sk/sk/rady-a-tipy/125-4-vyhody-plastovych-okien

if you use this link:

http://www.cedera-okna.sk/sk/rady-a-tipy/125-4-vyhody-plastovych-o

you will get same page without getting 404 error.

I know it is crazy but I need to get 404 error if the link is not perfect.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla loads the articles in basis of **article id**

## How is Alias used in a URL?

For a menu item, Joomla! uses the alias as the URL plug. Assume that you use the first two SEF URL options and you create a menu item called Products. Your URL would be example.com/products.

Joomla! also uses the primary key values of data within the URL to help the router navigate to the correct page. Continuing with the previous example, if your products menu item was for an Article­/Category Blog, the link for the Article Title and/or Read More link would have three parts:

1. The menu item URL - example.com/products;
2. Plus, the primary key for the Category and the Category alias -
   32-fruit;
3. Plus, the primary key for the Article and the Article alias -
   1-apple;

The complete URL is: http://example.com/products/32-fruit/1-apple

So if you check the url

http://www.cedera-okna.sk/sk/rady-a-tipy/125

it will also work.

For more information, check here

https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs

Comment: Thank you for your answer, So there is no way to do this withou developing new router logic?